# How to use redux-state-sync middleware with angular-redux?

Tags: angular, redux, angular-redux

I have existing code where I have configured the store in AppModule constructor:

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IApplicationState>) {

  // Tell @angular-redux/store about our rootReducer and our initial state.
  // It will use this to create a redux store for us and wire up all the
  // events.
  ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
}
```

This is pretty much how the documentation tells to use it.

Now I'm trying to use [redux-state-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-state-sync) with my store. However the redux-state-sync documentation's example instructs me to use createStore instead of configureStore:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { createStateSyncMiddleware } from 'redux-state-sync';

const config = {
  // TOGGLE_TODO will not be triggered in other tabs
  blacklist: ['TOGGLE_TODO'],
}
const middlewares = [
  createStateSyncMiddleware(config),
];
 
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

If I try to add the middleware to configureStore:

```
ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

I get error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(51,56): error TS2345: Argument of type
>   'StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: {}; }, {}>' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>[]'.   Type
>   'StoreEnhancer<{ dispatch: {}; }, {}>' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>[]':
>   pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.

How can I use redux-state-sync with angular-redux?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I can do like this:

```
const config = {
  blacklist: ['TOGGLE_TODO'],
}
const middlewares : Middleware[] = [
  createStateSyncMiddleware(config),
];
ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, middlewares);
```

but it seems like the state changes are not synced to other tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't get this to work properly on broadcast-channel (see [Why redux @select does not work even though the state is changed when using redux-state-sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146026/why-redux-select-does-not-work-even-though-the-state-is-changed-when-using-redu)) so here it is with localstorage.

app.module.ts

```
import { createStateSyncMiddleware, initStateWithPrevTab } from 'redux-state-sync';
import { Store, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

export const store: Store<IApplicationState> = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware({ broadcastChannelOption: { type: 'localstorage' } })
);

export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<any>) {
    initStateWithPrevTab(store);
    ngRedux.provideStore(store);
  }
 }
```

store/index.ts

```
import { combineReducers  } from 'redux'
import { ILoginState, loginReducer } from './login'
import { withReduxStateSync } from 'redux-state-sync'

export interface IApplicationState {
  login: ILoginState;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE : IApplicationState = {
   login : { isLoggedIn: false, tokenInfo : null } 
}

const appReducer = combineReducers<IApplicationState>({
  login: loginReducer
})

export const rootReducer = withReduxStateSync(appReducer);
```