# How to find out what breaks Angular binding?

Tags: angular

I have angular [app](https://bitbucket.org/em-aitch/sync-app/src/master/) supporting multiple browser tabs that has 2 bindings other using angular-redux @select and other one {{ property }}. The app works as expected. However I can break the bindings by configuring my angular store using redux-state-sync middleware to use broadcast-channel instead of localstorage. So replacing a row with a commented row below it in app.component.ts breaks the bindings in 2nd browser window. This seems really strange and I have no idea how to find out why both bindings break from seemingly unrelated change.

EDIT: Refering to yurzui's answer: **the state is synced across the tabs also with broadcast-channel option. Only the bindings don't work anymore**. This can be verified in console output in different browser tabs when button is pressed.

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">
    <p>this appears when logged in!</p>
  </div>
  <h1>
    App status is {{ statusTxt }}!
  </h1>
  <button (click)="toggleLogin()">{{ buttonTxt }}</button>
  <h2>You can either login 1st and then open another tab or you can 1st open another tab and then login. Either way the both tabs should be logged in and look the same</h2>
  <h2>After testing multiple tabs with current 'localstorage' broadcastChannelOption type, you can change it to 'native' in app.component.ts and you'll see that bindings do not work anymore</h2>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createStateSyncMiddleware, initStateWithPrevTab, withReduxStateSync } from 'redux-state-sync';
import { combineReducers, Action, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { NgRedux, select } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export interface LoginToggle {
  isLoggedIn : boolean
}

export interface LoginToggleAction extends Action {
  loginToggle: LoginToggle;
}

@Injectable()
export class LoginActions {
  static TOGGLE_LOGIN = 'TOGGLE_LOGIN';

  toggleLogin(loginToggle: LoginToggle): LoginToggleAction {
    return { 
        type: LoginActions.TOGGLE_LOGIN, 
        loginToggle 
    };
  }
}

export interface ILoginState {
  readonly isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

export interface IApplicationState {
  login: ILoginState;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE : IApplicationState = {
   login : { isLoggedIn: false } 
}

export function loginReducer(oldState: ILoginState = { isLoggedIn : false } as any, action: Action) : ILoginState {
  switch (action.type) {
      case LoginActions.TOGGLE_LOGIN: {
          console.log('in reducer');
          const toggleAction = action as LoginToggleAction;
          return {
              ...oldState,
              isLoggedIn: toggleAction.loginToggle.isLoggedIn
          } as ILoginState;       
      }
      default: {
        return oldState;
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  statusTxt = 'logged out';
  subscription;
  loginStatus = false;
  buttonTxt = 'Login';

  @select((state: IApplicationState) => state.login.isLoggedIn) isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IApplicationState>, 
    private actions : LoginActions) {

    const appReducer = combineReducers<IApplicationState>({
      login: loginReducer
    })

    const rootReducer = withReduxStateSync(appReducer);
    const store = createStore(rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware({ broadcastChannelOption: { type: 'localstorage' } })));

    /* !! Both bindings break if i replace the row above with this: 
    applyMiddleware(createStateSyncMiddleware())); */

    initStateWithPrevTab(store);

    ngRedux.provideStore(store);

    this.subscription = this.ngRedux.select<ILoginState>('login')
      .subscribe(newState => {
        console.log('new login state = ' + newState.isLoggedIn);
        this.loginStatus = newState.isLoggedIn;
        if (newState.isLoggedIn) {
          this.statusTxt = 'logged in!';
          this.buttonTxt = 'Logout';
        }
        else { 
          this.statusTxt = 'logged out!';
          this.buttonTxt = 'Login';
        }
        console.log('statusTxt = ' + this.statusTxt);
    });
  }

  toggleLogin(): void {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.toggleLogin({ isLoggedIn: !this.loginStatus }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use localstorage channel your application is subscribed to browser [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent) event. And once your application changes the value in one tab it updates locastorage which fires `storage` event in other tab so it's updated.

With default `redux_state_sync` channel you don't have such connection between tabs but channel now uses [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) which **is not patched by zonejs** so you always get message not in angular zone.

What can you do?

**Manually run code inside Angular zone** on subscribe:

```
constructor(...private zone: NgZone) {

this.subscription = this.ngRedux.select<ILoginState>('login')
  .subscribe(newState => {
    this.zone.run(() => {  // enforce the code to be executed inside Angular zone
      console.log('new login state = ' + newState.isLoggedIn);
      this.loginStatus = newState.isLoggedIn;
      ...
    })
});
```

Please do notice that you can also run cdRef.detectChanges but in this case you can **get into a situation when some of Angular handlers will be registered outside of Angular zone**. **As a result you will have call detectChanges in other places or again use zone.run**.

So I would suggest you using zone.run to make sure that you are in the right zone within Angular application

Comment: thanks for your answer, but did you try it? there's supposed to be broadcastchannel connection between tabs. and it also works to some extent. the state is synced across the tabs but the bindings to gui does not work. you can easily verify this in console output.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i have to check this out later properly as i'm not familiar with zones.

Comment: thanks again! this works for redux state change listener. is there a way to make the select binding work also? if not, it's no a big deal. i also wonder if there's way to run all redux state change listeners inside angular zone without explicitly making each of them  like in the above? this is easy thing to forget an lose time figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not running in the angular cycle hook.

You can manually ask to angular to run the ckech with the method `detectChanges()` from the  `ChangeDetectorRef` class.

You have to add in the constructor the `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
 constructor(
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IApplicationState>, 
    private actions : LoginActions,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
   ) {

    const appReducer = combineReducers<IApplicationState>({
      login: loginReducer
    })
```

And then in the subscription the `detectChanges`:

```
this.subscription = this.ngRedux.select<ILoginState>('login')
      .subscribe(newState => {
        console.log('new login state = ' + newState.isLoggedIn);
        this.loginStatus = newState.isLoggedIn;
        if (newState.isLoggedIn) {
          this.statusTxt = 'logged in!';
          this.buttonTxt = 'Logout';
        } else { 
          this.statusTxt = 'logged out!';
          this.buttonTxt = 'Login';
        }
        console.log('statusTxt = ' + this.statusTxt);
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! i have to check this out later properly.

Comment: It should, I have this in some parts of my code. Could you upload a "not" working example in stackblitz?

Comment: I tried to create stackblitz, but it is not building even though it suggested correct missing packages and i clicked install for the packages. So i created a branch in my repository: bcc-detect-changes. You can easily check it does not work.